# Написание RTS с генетическими алгоритмами и нейросетями на C# с 0

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, нейронные-сети, unity3d

В общем очень сильно хочу создать "игру" а скорее эксперимент в виде игры по генетическим алгоритмам с нейронными сетями и кучей всяких таких фич, что бы сделать очень необычных ботов для игры. Необычный ИИ и необычный геймплей.

Я предполагаю, что игра будет выглядить сверху, а графика в стиле примерно таком

[image: Imgur]

Планирую процедурную генерацию всего чего только можно. Графика не важна. Всякие фичи типа SSAO и так далее, которые привносят дешёвый реализм приветствую. 
Требования у меня такие к движку или просто к "способу разработки".
Документация понятная с примера и желательно с ру комьюнити, хотя можно и просто мануалы на англ.
Легкое вхождение (то есть не надо качать 1000 библиотек, а потом писать 1000 строк кода что бы каждую подключить настроить и тд..)

Всякие попсовые движки лучше не советуйте (unity cryengine unreal), потому, что они мне сейчас не нужны.

Я хочу по быстрому сделать эксперимент и понять, что к чему и как работает в мелочах. Как там все это рендерится. Ну короче покрутить гайки и поиграться с кодом.

А если уже потом получиться, то тогда перенесу на какой-то платный движок и лет-го-го-го.

У меня есть опыт в верстке сайтов и всяких мелочах и создании небольших приложений на C# (алгоритм генерации торговли, крутая штука кстати) , так что я не полный чайник.

Простой я вот сейчас кинулся, куча всяких движков, и фич типа XNA даже не знаю с чего начать!

Помогите советом. Я уже всю ветку хабра habrahabr.ru/hub/gdev и по алгоритма наизусть знаю.

И да, не советуйте всякое старьё которое сейчас не актуально. У меня Win7 и Visual Studio 2012, всё что ниже не советуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашей задачи не получится "покрутить гайки и поиграться с кодом". Это можно сделать чтобы понять особенности конректного средства разработки. Вам же сейчас наибольший смысл имеет реализовывать **логику** вашей игры, с выводом хоть в консоль.

И да, в одиночку такую задачу просто не потянуть.

Comment: А можно ли сначала реализовать логику как вы сказали, а потом перенести её на какой-то движок?

Comment: конечно. Поставьте для себя задачу реализации алгоритма, и потом перенесите ее в, допустим, тот же самый Unity

Comment: Ну значит раз так тогда задам уже следующий вопрос.

Comment: Кстати XNA для такой разработки тоже подойдет. Задача проработать алгоритм, а вывод организовать и 2d можно: кружочками и квадратиками разных цветов.

Answer (score 5):

[@Kimel](/users/20586/kimel), все это прекрасно, но настолько срезать углы не получится. Не получится в короткие сроки написать безбажный движок, не получится освоить столько материала, не получится пройти весь путь без серьезны застреваний на каких-то этапах. У вас уже заявлено как минимум три серьезные разработки:

- "Необычный" ИИ
- Игра по генетическим алгоритмам (?)
- Движок

Каждая из них способна занять год у талантливого программиста.

> У меня есть опыт в верстке сайтов и всяких мелочах и создании небольших приложений на C#

Боюсь, это поможет разве что в XAML-разметке (а она там будет вообще?)

Comment: Можете подсказать, сколько будет стоить разработка подобного приложения в Unity3D?
Действительно строить свой движок нет смысла, но можно ли подобные замыслы реализовать там? И насколько юнити так сказать дружит с подобными вещами?

Comment: @Kimel, не могу, я в этом деле не кипятился, не представляю, сколько конкретно затрат уходит на тот или иной аспект. И без четкого ТЗ границы стоимости могут варьироваться очень сильно.